# OR logic and CONTAINS in a query in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I have a problem with an OR logic in a query. I'm trying to make a sum of a column (D), if:

• column A = `cars/build-price/carselector.html`

• column B = contains `ateca` or `ibiza` (the cell could be "get the ateca", "new ibiza xx", ...)

• column C = `footer`

First tried with a SUMIFS but didn't work:

```
=SUMIFS(C:C;A:A;"cars/build-price/carselector.html";B:B;{"ateca"; "ibiza"};D:D;"footer")
```

then tried with a QUERY, but I don't really know this language:

```
=SUM(QUERY(A:D;"Select C where A='cars/build-price/carselector.html' and D='footer' and (B='ateca' or B='ibiza')"))
```

Can't find how to fit the "contains" and the "or" logic.

Someone can help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A query could be:

```
=QUERY(A:D,"select sum(D) where A='cars/build-price/carselector.html' and C='footer' and (B contains 'ateca' or B contains 'ibiza')")
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula:

`=SUMPRODUCT(C:C,ArrayFormula((A:A="cars/build-price/carselector.html")*(D:D="footer")*((N(REGEXMATCH(B:B,"ateca")))+(N(REGEXMATCH(B:B,"ibiza"))))))`